# Shortening Magento Generated Image URLs

Tags: magento

Is there a way / extension to have the image URLs generated by Magento shortened from:
http://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/325x325/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/a/image_01_site_01.jpg

To something more acceptable like: http://www.website.com/images/image_01_site_01.jpg

Comment: you can always generate rewrite rules with mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cached image you must use the long url. If you want a shorter URL you could change it, and it will pull a non cached image:

Replace this:

```
http://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/325x325/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/m/a/image_01_site_01.jpg
```

With this:

```
http://www.website.com/media/catalog/product/m/a/image_01_site_01.jpg
```